# C++ _findfirst and TCHAR

Tags: c++, argv, tchar, findfirst

I've been given the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    _finddata_t dirEntry;
    intptr_t dirHandle;
    dirHandle = _findfirst("C:/*", &dirEntry);
    int res = (int)dirHandle;
    while(res != -1) {
        cout << dirEntry.name << endl;
        res = _findnext(dirHandle, &dirEntry);
    }
    _findclose(dirHandle);
    cin.get();
   return (0);
}
```

what this does is printing the name of everything that the given directory (C:) contains. Now I have to make this print out the name of everything in the subdirectories (if there are any) as well. I've got this so far:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    _finddata_t dirEntry;
    intptr_t dirHandle;
    dirHandle = _findfirst(argv[1], &dirEntry);
    vector<string> dirArray;
    int res = (int)dirHandle;
    unsigned int attribT;
    while (res != -1) {
        cout << dirEntry.name << endl;
        res = _findnext(dirHandle, &dirEntry);
        attribT = (dirEntry.attrib >> 4) & 1; //put the fifth bit into a temporary variable
//the fifth bit of attrib says if the current object that the _finddata instance contains is a folder.
        if (attribT) { //if it is indeed a folder, continue (has been tested and confirmed already)
            dirArray.push_back(dirEntry.name);
            cout << "Pass" << endl;
            //res = _findfirst(dirEntry.name, &dirEntry); //needs to get a variable which is the dirEntry.name combined with the directory specified in argv[1].
    }
}
_findclose(dirHandle);
std::cin.get();
return (0);
```

}

Now I'm not asking for the whole solution (I want to be able to do it on my own) but there is just this one thing I can't get my head around which is the TCHAR* argv. I know argv[1] contains what I put in my project properties under "command arguments", and right now this contains the directory I want to test my application in (C:/users/name/New folder/*), which contains some folders with subfolders and some random files. 
The argv[1] currently gives the following error:

> Error: argument of type "_TCHAR*" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Now I've googled for the TCHAR and I understand it is either a wchar_t* or a char* depending on using Unicode character set or multi-byte character set (I'm currently using Unicode). I also understand converting is a massive pain. So what I'm asking is: how can I best go around this with the _TCHAR and _findfirst parameter?

I'm planning to concat the dirEntry.name to the argv[1] as well as concatenating a "*" on the end, and using this in another _findfirst. Any comments on my code are appreciated as well since I'm still learning C++.

Comment: `_TCHAR` is a macro that should have been defined in "windows.h".  Are you including this header?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015 with a precompiled header, so I guess so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple `typedef`:

`typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> TCharString;`

Then use `TCharString` wherever you were using `std::string`, such as here:

```
vector<TCharString> dirArray;
```

See here for information on [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Will this act the same as a regular std::string?

Comment: @Arrrow -- That's the beauty of this template -- yes, it should work exactly like `std::string`.  Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 2):

See here: [_findfirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/zyzxfzac.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is for multibyte strings while `_wfindfirst` is for wide characters. If you use TCHAR in your code then use `_tfindfirst` (macro) which will resolve to _findfirst on non UNICODE, and _wfindfirst on UNICODE builds.

Also instead of _finddata_t use _tfinddata_t which will also resolve to correct structure depending on UNICODE config.

Another thing is that you should use also correct literal, `_T("C:/*")` will be `L"C:/*"` on UNICODE build, and `"C:/*"` otherwise. If you know you are building with UNICODE defined, then use `std::vector<std::wstring>`.

btw. Visual Studio by default will create project with UNICODE, you may use only wide versions of functions like `_wfindfirst` as there is no good reason to build non UNICODE projects.

> TCHAR and I understand it is either a wchar_t* or a char* depending on using UTF-8 character set or multi-byte character set (I'm currently using UTF-8).

this is wrong, in UNICODE windows apis uses UTF-16. `sizeof(wchar_t)==2`.

Comment: So it is either change to _tfindfirst/_tfinddata_t or get rid of the TCHAR completely?

Comment: Visual Studio will generate code using TCHAR.h so to stay consistent its better to use TCHAR.h. Those mapping you may find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szdfzttz.aspx. But in your code you may use wide versions of functions - code will compile. I personally use TCHAR.h.

Comment: @Arrrow actually your code should "magically" start working once you change in project settings: General->Character Set to 'Use Multi-Byte Character Set'. But I suggest you stay with UNICODE and fix your code.